# Can urllib.parse.quote_plus support lowercase?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

Here is an url, like https://www.example.com?timestamp={timestamp}&sign={sign}

And I have caculated the sigh by some algorithm, and got the flowing value.
`org_sign = "HBwZu47FkVdQGTyd7uLjfVAQA8nBSwqvE/x3Xv/KFNE="`.

Now I want to encode the value and add it to the url.

In urllib.parse.quote_plus, the `'/' => '%2F'`, and `'='=>'%3D'`, so I got `'HBwZu47FkVdQGTyd7uLjfVAQA8nBSwqvE%2Fx3Xv%2FKFNE%3D'` .

But I want `%2f` and `%3d`, and then `HBwZu47FkVdQGTyd7uLjfVAQA8nBSwqvE%2fx3Xv%2fKFNE%3d`. And I cannot change the whole sign to a lower case directly, like `sign.lower()`. Because it is a sign, it is case-sensitive.

Python 3.7.2

```
>>> from urllib import parse 
>>> org_sign = "HBwZu47FkVdQGTyd7uLjfVAQA8nBSwqvE/x3Xv/KFNE="
>>> parse.quote_plus(org_sign) 
'HBwZu47FkVdQGTyd7uLjfVAQA8nBSwqvE%2Fx3Xv%2FKFNE%3D'
```

And I read the [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse) in urllib. It doesn't mention any thing about case-sensitive.

Comment: From the urllib.parse.Quoter, I found the flowing code,  
`def __missing__(self, b):
        # Handle a cache miss. Store quoted string in cache and return.
        res = chr(b) if b in self.safe else '%{:02X}'.format(b)
        self[b] = res
        return res`

Answer (score 2):

This workaround works for me:

```
import urllib.parse


class LowerCaseQuoter(urllib.parse.Quoter):
    def __missing__(self, b):
        # Handle a cache miss. Store quoted string in cache and return.
        res = chr(b) if b in self.safe else '%{:02x}'.format(b)
        self[b] = res
        return res

urllib.parse._safe_quoters[b''] = LowerCaseQuoter(b'').__getitem__
```

Original string: /media/Filmy/PohadkyCD/Sofie Prvni/Season 1 (2013-2014) + pilot/1x00.Sofie První, Byla jednou jedna princezna (Once Upon a Princess).avi

Encoded string by urllib.parse.quote(filename, safe=''): %2fmedia%2fFilmy%2fPohadkyCD%2fSofie%20Prvni%2fSeason%201%20%282013-2014%29%20%2b%20pilot%2f1x00.Sofie%20Prvn%c3%ad%2c%20Byla%20jednou%20jedna%20princezna%20%28Once%20Upon%20a%20Princess%29.avi